# Regular expression to remove specific multi-byte characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to remove specific multi-byte characters in R.

```
Multibyte <- "Sungpil_한성필_韓盛弼_Han"
```

The linguistic structure of `Multibyte` is "English_Korean_Chinese_English" What I want to remove is the Korean word only or Chinese word only (not both).

A desired result is either :

```
Sungpil_한성필__Han   # Chinese characters were removed.
```

or

```
Sungpil__韓盛弼_Han   # Korean characters were removed.
```

Is there a simple way to do it by using `gsub`? I am only aware of a method to get English-only characters.

```
gsub("[^A-Za-z_]", "", Multibyte)
[1] "Sungpil___Han"
```

Comment: Which characters do you want to remove/retain?

Comment: Regular expressions deal with characters, not bytes. Have you tried using the actual characters you need?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I specified the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question itself, yes, you may do it with a mere `gsub` using a PCRE regex and Unicode property classes `\p{Hangul}` for matching Korean chars, and `\p{Han}` to match Chinese chars:

```
> Multibyte <- "Sungpil_한성필_韓盛弼_Han"
> gsub("\\p{Hangul}+", "",Multibyte, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Sungpil__韓盛弼_Han"
> gsub("\\p{Han}+", "",Multibyte, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Sungpil_한성필__Han"
```

See [R online demo](https://ideone.com/owdovd).

However, if you have a specific structure of the input text, use the other solution.

Comment: Awesome! Neat and simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just FYI: `+` is a quantifier that matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern. If you remove it, it will still yield the same result, just it will be removing character by character.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `sub`

```
sub("[^_]+_([A-Za-z]+)$", "_\\1", Multibyte)
#[1] "Sungpil_한성필__Han"
```

Comment: Thank you, akrun. This helps but I wonder if there's a regexr that recognizes specific language characters. I'm doubtful though.

Comment: @SungpilHan You might be able to target certain unicode ranges, if R has the ability to do this.